# How to put SDK into JFrog artifactory?

Tags: android, sdk, artifactory

I have an Android SDK. I want to put the SDK into JFrog Artifactory. How can I do that?

Comment: would you like to deploy the sdk file into artifactory using curl or the UI?

Comment: @MuhammedKashif both will work for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For UI deployment, kindly refer to this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Deploying+Artifacts) page for all the steps. For the curl deployment, you can deploy any files to any repositories as below,

> curl -u myUser:myP455w0rd! -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-repository/myfile.sdk" -T Desktop/myfile.sdk